# Error while importing filtrr2.js in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use Filtrr2.js(https://github.com/alexmic/filtrr/tree/master/filtrr2) library in my react application.
Since no npm is present for this library, I have downloaded the js in **src** folder files and provided the path in index.html, like below:

```
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/camanjs/4.1.2/caman.full.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/plugins/filtrr2.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/plugins/util.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/plugins/effects.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/plugins/layers.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/plugins/events.js"></script>
  </body>
```

and then in app.js in componentDidMount I'm trying to console like this

```
console.log(window.filtrr2);
```

but this return undefined and also I'm getting the below error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <filtrr2.js:1
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <util.js:1 
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <effects.js:1 
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <layers.js:1 
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <events.js:1
```

Can anyone help how to use this library in React??

Comment: Are you sure all the script files are loaded when React initialises? You can use window.addEventListener(“load”,...) to check that.

Comment: Also, filtrr seems to be 7 years old, which is like the stone age in internet time

Comment: @Kokodoko reason for using this lib is that it supports TINT, however glfx.js is a great lib and works like a charm, unfortunately it does provide TINT. This is reason I was giving  a try to this lib. Let me know in case if you know how to apply tint using glfx.js.